# How to find the duplicates in a text file and write the values with no duplicates to a text file?

Tags: .net, vbscript

I was trying to write a script that took a text file and read it to look for any duplicate values. The Code below writes the duplicates to a text file and the values with the duplicates to a text file. But how would I write the values without any duplicates on a separate value.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\predata.txt", 

ForReading)
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop

\Noduplicates.txt", 2, True)
Set objOutputFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop

\Duplicates.txt", 2, True)
Set objOutputFile3 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop

\alone.txt", 2, True)
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do until objFile.atEndOfStream
    strCurrentLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If not Dict.Exists(strCurrentLine) then 
        objOutputFile.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        Dict.Add strCurrentLine,strCurrentLine
    ElseIf Dict.Exists(strCurrentLine) then 
        objOutputFile2.WriteLine strCurrentLine

    Else
        objOutputFile3.WriteLine strCurrentLine
    End if 
Loop
wscript.echo "Finished"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect/write uniques/elms without dups on the fly/while reading the input - the last line could make an element non-unique. So **count** the elements during the input loop and write the classified elements to different files after that.

**Code to illustrate:**

```
>> a = Split("a b c a b b")
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> For Each e In a
>>     d(e) = d(e) + 1
>> Next
>>
>> For Each e In d.Keys
>>     WScript.Echo d(e), e
>> Next
>>
2 a
3 b
1 c
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a count with the associated dictionary entry. Every time you match a line, increase its count in the dictionary. When you've finished reading the file, go through the dictionary again and output every line that has a count of 1.

Alternately, you can sort the file and go through it sequentially. My vbscript skills have atrophied, but the general idea is:

```
string prevLine = read first line
bool isDup = false
for each remaining line
    if (line != prevLine)
        if (!isDup)
            line has no duplicates
        prevLine = line
        isDup = false
    else
        isDup = true
```

For sorting the file, take a look at the [Windows SORT program](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sort.mspx?mfr=true).

If you can install the GNU/Linux utilities, check out `sort` and `uniq`. They will let you do this without having to write any code.